# Full contact moderating

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, fun, vote-to-reopen

We've all seen, and most have participated in, more than one open/close war.  Things are said.  Feelings are hurt.  It's very personal for many of us, and yet so impersonal due to the lack of face time with your accusers.

So I'm asking that SO implement full-contact moderation.  Once a question gets 5 votes to close, and 5 subsequent votes to open, the question is locked until the affected parties meet in a brawl type setting, where they can duke it out.

This way others online can see which side has greater numbers or is more likely to win (due to the impact of their arguments on the opposing force) and choose which side of the debate they'll take in real time.

There may be implementation details to be worked out, but I think the idea is generally sound and wanted to open a discussion before officially making a feature request.

Comment: Added the appropriate tag :)

Comment: +1 For a sense of humor.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is an accepted, recognized and proven way to solve any dispute.

[image: You fight like a dairy farmer.]

Comment: +1, Guybrush Threepwood and Largo are missed!

Comment: Oh yeah, well you fight like a cow! I sense my next name change ... Only ... Guybrush ... or LeChuck?

Comment: Who downvoted Monkey Island? Poor soul, I will pray for you ...

Comment: "How appropriate, you fight like a cow!"

Comment: @blorgbeard: Dangit, you're right; I screwed up the first part of it! Ah, good times. I've been (off-and-on) playing the redo of Monkey Island on XBox Arcade recently ... Such fond memories.

Comment: *cough* I think StackOverflow should also add the alt-text of an image as a title tag, so that xkcd-style tooltips work :P

Comment: "People fall at my feet when they see me coming."

Comment: @Gnoupi: "Even BEFORE they smell your breath?"

Comment: @Michael: I get the tooltip on hover.

Comment: Love that game.

Comment: I added it after getting the hint on how to do that on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35995 :-)

Comment: I just coughed cider. A true blast from my mis-spent past.

Comment: @Marc You can make it your mis-spent present again :-) http://store.steampowered.com/app/32360/

Comment: @Michael: Ah yes, that's the remix I'm referring to -- available on XBox Live too. :)

Comment: Hurray, a winner is you!

Comment: Yay, Mortarboard badge :D

Comment: Image link is broken

Answer (score 4):

## eRabble

[Rabble http://xs.to/image-613A_4B510A74.jpg](http://xs.to/image-613A_4B510A74.jpg)

Am I right in thinking a serious answer isn't required?

[There was a massive body of text here. But I think I missed the tone of the question]

Comment: I know what this is from but I do have to say that (unfortunately) this is how I see every single Wikipedia editor in my mind.

Comment: This is how I see anyone on the internet, until I know otherwise. Better safe than sorry!

Answer (score 3):

> The first rule of <strike>Fight
>   Club</strike>Stack Overflow is that
>   you do not talk about <strike>Fight
>   Club</strike>Stack Overflow.
>
> Now I see a lot of new faces tonight,
>   so it looks like some of you have been
>   breaking rule #1.

It has to be bare-knuckle brawling until one opponent taps out. Two men to a fight. Only one fight at a time. And if this your first night, you **have** to fight.

> Boss: Is that your blood?
>
> Protagonist: Some of it, yeah.

Answer (score 3):

[fight! http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/6684/nerdfightg.jpg](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/6684/nerdfightg.jpg)

Paint it red ... **no** .. paint it green ... fight!

Comment: Damn, a man-purse!

Answer (score 2):

It may not need be fisticuffs.  I'm thinking that some participants will choose other games, such as Mario Kart, Rock Paper Scissors, Roshambo, tug-o-war, Battleship, etc.

What forms of brawling do you prefer?
What limitations do we need to deal with? (ie, if there are 20+ people involved, a mario kart tournament can take quite a bit of time, but a roshambo free-for-all might only take *seconds* ...)

Comment: Fastest to log in to SO and vote to close 5 questions?

Comment: Two men enter, one man leaves.  **Thunderdome**

Comment: What's Roshambo?

Comment: @mmyers: first of all, it's spelled **rochambeau**, second of all, http://www.southparkstudios.com/clips/103724

Answer (score 2):

It would take a little work to implement but perhaps a **workable solution** would be for it to turn into a poll (after 5 votes each way), showing how many votes each side has. Once there's a preset differential, say 10 clear votes, the question can be locked as either closed or opened, with any further voting disabled.

Being a global website punch-ups can be a little difficult to organise. Besides which, cattle prods at 5 paces is probably more fun and less damaging.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be up for [Fake Plastic Rock](http://www.fakeplasticrock.com/).