# Encourage people to use alt text

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accessibility, alt-text

People should be encouraged to use alt text when they upload images to questions or answers.

Even experienced users with 110K rep have forgotten to do so at least one times.

A tooltip would be overkill, but a message on top of the preview box would be nice.

**Update**: Arjan [suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74348/should-a-badge-be-awarded-for-images/74353#74353) awarding a badge for adding custom alt text.

Comment: Why not use the filename for the default alt text? But then all search results for Untitled.bmp will point to SO sites

Comment: @abel, I think most file names are not suitable as alt text.

Comment: Alt what? I can't recall I ever filled in anything

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: Are you joking or serious?

Comment: I'm dead serious @Andrew, I just upload my pictures and be done with it

Comment: @Ivo: So you'd need more in-your-face notification that you aren't using alt text and that you ought to be doing so?

Comment: As for good alt text: see [How to write good alt text for images to help screen reader and blind user to understand what is picture about?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741700/how-to-write-good-alt-text-for-images-to-help-screen-reader-and-blind-user-to-und/1741983#1741983)

Comment: That depends how descriptive my text around it is, I don't tend to 'just' post an image.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I changed it from

> alt text

to

> enter image description here

and we'll see if that helps or not. Personally I doubt it, but the copy is better at least.

Answer (score 15):

In my opinion alt-text on images is less about the preview box and more about accessibility, and for that it's important to know [how to use alt-text properly](http://www.abilitynet.org.uk/blog/five-golden-rules-compliant-alt-text). So while I agree alt-texts should be used more, it's also important to know how to do it.

Answer (score 12):

Remember that empty alt texts (ie. `<img alt="" src="image.png" />`) **are acceptable** if the alternative content is repeated immediately before or after the image, or if the image does not serve any important semantic purposes.

The most frustrating thing, however, is that by default the filler 'alt text' is filled in the alt text blank for images, and more than 90% of the time this is left in the post after submitting. This is not to fault the post authors - coming up with a valid textual alternative to images is hard, and sometimes as notes above sometimes there's no need for a textual alternative for the images.

That said, having no alt text at all would arguably be better than having half a dozen 'alt text' images strewn across posts. The editor should, if possible, remove the filler text automatically when the post is submitted.

Answer (score 9):

Requesting alt text in the image-upload GUI, as per [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231949/could-image-description-be-input-in-the-add-image-dialog-box-while-uploading-ima), would be an effective and natural way to encourage people to enter meaningful alt text, especially if it comes with a well-crafted explanation of what is needed and why.