# Should a badge be awarded for images?

Tags: discussion, badges

Should a badge be awarded for adding images to a question or answer, like there are for using other aspects of a Stack Exchange web site such as editing a post?

[image: Text of the question, in Opening Crawl text]

Comment: I would upvote for presentation; however, I don't think a badge should be awarded for images. Creative use, presentation, etc. are rewarded by upvotes, IMO.

Comment: Sounds [great for me](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:145982+so.mrozekma.com)

Comment: @Michael: I don't understand the punchline of your link.

Comment: I almost always include an image in my meta posts; so.mrozekma.com is the domain the images are hosted on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*If* ever implemented, then instead of awarding it for the image, please award it when the user [sets a custom alt text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74048/encourage-people-to-use-alt-text).

(He, that's your feature request too! Maybe the encouragement for setting the alt text could be a badge then?)

Answer (score 15):

[image: Aw Hell Naw - Obama]

Seriously though: Using a badge to make people aware of the feature is a honourable idea at first, but the image feature is **not essential for providing good content**. Many SO users get by without ever using an image, and there are *many* ways of harming the site through images. Therefore, I think this is not a feature that should be explicitly pointed out.

Comment: (@Andrew, now I'm wondering what a screen reader makes out of that alt text!)

Answer (score 5):

No.

If you award badges for images, they are awarded for good and bad images.

If you have an answer with a good (appropriate) image it will be awarded with upvotes.

Besides if you start awarding images, why not awarding links, or pieces of code. Its all part of the content and the content is responsible for the up and downvotes.

Comment: I wish there was a badge for highlighting pieces of code. Besides, couldn't the same logic be applied for the "Editor" badge (there's good and bad edits)?

Comment: @Andrew but an edit is *supposed* to be an improvement. A series of harmful edits will have consequences for the user. A series of useless images can't be "prosecuted" in  the same way