# Use the image URL as default alt text?

Tags: feature-request, images, alt-text

[Since today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74048/encourage-people-to-use-alt-text/76103#76103) the image uploader inserts an image using:

```
![enter image description here][https://i.stack.imgur.com/blah]
```

I'm sure that the previous default value, `alt text`, made no sense and almost nobody changed it to something meaningful.

So how about to change it to the same URL as image's URL? i.e.

```
![https://i.stack.imgur.com/blah](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blah)
```

which will make sense for a person with turned off, etc images.

Comment: Do you really think `http://i.imgur.com/tJWuU.png` is any more meaningful than `alt text`?

Comment: @balpha: That's real image URL. In case of turned off images, it will be helpfull

Comment: And now pretend you're using a screen reader?

Comment: This would delight me greatly, as our net-nanny at work has imgur blocked.

Comment: @Jason, then what would you learn from `tJWuU.png`? And what browser are you using that displays the alt text when images fail to load?

Comment: @Arjan, I would figure out a little more easily that there was supposed to be an image there, rather than wondering why the author chose to have a paragraph with an apparent sentence fragment in it (in the case that the default "alt text" is not used). I see the alt text in Firefox and/or Chrome IIRC.

Comment: Aha, @Jason, I never noticed: indeed all my browsers show the alt text if the image is large enough to fit it. My Firefox 4 beta is the only one to *only* show that text and *not* show some placeholder using the image dimensions — which I guess is bad for formatting (at least when dimensions have been explicitly set).

Comment: Related: the default text [has just been changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74048/encourage-people-to-use-alt-text/76103#76103) to *"enter image description here"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the URL is, in my opinion, useless - it's a data most people don't care about, and those that do can access it via right-clicking the image and copying its URL, or examining the page source.

I agree that leaving the "alt text" text there is even worse, but if anything we need to encourage people to just [write alt text properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74048/encourage-people-to-use-alt-text). As far as screen readers go, putting the URL as the alt text is probably worse than just making it an empty string.

Comment: Agreed, except for that leaving "alt text" would be worse. Just imagine hearing a screen reader trying to read `http://i.imgur.com/tJWuU.png`. (Still: +1 for the good link!)

Comment: @Arjan: Does anybody on SO use screen reader? Come on!

Comment: @abatish see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118984/how-can-you-program-if-youre-blind/148880#148880

Comment: Considering that it's a point of bitter debate amongst English pedants whether it's acceptable to use "data" as a mass noun (e.g. "the data shows X") rather than as a plural (e.g. "the data show X"), the use of the definitely-incorrect singular *"a data"* here is rather delightful.