# Images use title text, not alt text

Tags: feature-request, alt-text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Also use alt tag as title on images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35995/also-use-alt-tag-as-title-on-images)

Alt text does not produce tooltips on Chrome (and maybe other standard compliant browsers).

> The alt attribute specifies alternate text that is rendered when the image cannot be displayed (see below for information on how to specify alternate text ). User agents must render alternate text when they cannot support images, they cannot support a certain image type or when they are configured not to display images. [(HTML 4.01 Spec, 13.2)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html)

The standard compliant browser will display only the image, or when that is not possible, only the alt text.

---

I propose using:

```
<img title="This is a tooltip." />
```

Instead of<s>, or in addition to</s>:

```
<img alt="This is NOT a tooltip." />
```

**EDIT:** I am not sure, but I don't think `alt` is valid HTML5.

---

> ### References
>
> http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200604/alt_text_is_an_alternative_not_a_tooltip/
>   http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2011/04/html5-accessibility-chops-the-alt-decision/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Markdown actually supports both. This:

```
![Foo](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo.png "Bar")
```

Turns into this:

```
<img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo.png" alt="Foo" title="Bar">
```

And looks like this:

[image: Foo]

Comment: Then shouldn't the image button produce `![Enter description here](http://example.com/example.jpg "")` so that users can realize that they can add title text?

Comment: @muntoo I suppose, but I doubt it would get used much; it's incredible how many images still have "Enter description here" as the alt text

Comment: @muntoo, no. The alt text is there for those who cannot see the image. Most often, that text should be different from its title.

Answer (score 9):

> Alt text does not produce tooltips on Chrome (and maybe other standard compliant browsers).

And what is the problem? This is how its spelt out in the specifications. `alt` is *alternative*, where you provide a text alternative to the pictorial content you're trying to display for users who cannot view the image. The distinction between `title` and `alt` is clear. If the user was confused, expecting what he typed in as the `alt` text to appear as `title` text, then we may have a problem with the user interface. But I presume this is not what you're asking for.

---

> EDIT: I am not sure, but I don't think `alt` is valid HTML5.

Huh?

> Except where otherwise specified, the `alt` attribute **must be specified** and its value must not be empty
>
> A corollary to this is that the `alt` attribute's value should never contain text that could be considered the image's *caption*, *title*, or *legend*. It is supposed to contain replacement text that could be used by users instead of the image; it is not meant to supplement the image. The `title` attribute can be used for supplemental information.
>
> [HTML5 specification edition for web developers](http://developers.whatwg.org/embedded-content-1.html#alt)

(Emphasis mine)