# SO server time sync?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, timestamps, gaming-the-system

This question suggests that the servers used in the SO rack are not properly time sync'd:

[Was a question asked in the future?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36591/question-asked-in-future)

- How are the servers clocks set?  (ie, NTP, or otherwise?)
- Are they synchronized to the same source, each other, or what configuration do you use?
- Do you have a single source you use, and what stratum level is it?
- Who assigns a timestamp to a given post - the Database, or HTTP server?

I'm not so concerned about keeping time exact with the rest of the world, this is primarily due to the possibility of gaming the system.

I can imagine a scenario where the web-facing servers are tested to find out which one is 'slowest' - several seconds behind the other servers - and then using that very slight advantage to exploit the FGITW issue.

This would only work if

- The servers are not adequately time synchronized (ie, to within a second)
- The HTTP servers assign the official post time to the post

Granted, it's a small advantage, and possibly not worth worrying about, but you may find that over time other interesting problems crop up if the systems are not properly time synchronized.  A good configuration using NTP should yield a server to server difference of less than 10mS - certainly enough to eliminate concerns over gaming, and to avoid other problems.

Comment: So .. when do the friday posts start?

Comment: Please, please, please don't tell me you're using the built-in windows time service... http://blogs.technet.com/askds/archive/2007/10/23/high-accuracy-w32time-requirements.aspx

Comment: @Chacha102 - Next Friday's posts start yesterday... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36557/does-stackoverflow-forget-their-registered-users/36559#36559

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database servers didn't have access to the internet any more, so their NTP calls to [pool.ntp.org](http://pool.ntp.org) were failing. We set up an internal NTP source for them.

edit: this time, the Windows Time service was mysteriously stopped on 5 of 6 web tier servers, even though it's set to "Autostart". I restarted it. Event log shows nothing relevant. Who knew NTP was so freakin' complicated?

Comment: But you're still using the windows time service?  Does the database or the webserver "record" the time when the post is submitted?