# Negative timestamp on SO

Tags: bug, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [SO server time sync?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36610/so-server-time-sync)
> [Question asked in future?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36591/question-asked-in-future)

I just came across a question where the timestamp was negative. See image.

[PHP Doctrine toArray problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156917/php-doctrine-toarray-problem)
[negative time http://ep2up.com/uploads/1264707916.png](http://ep2up.com/uploads/1264707916.png)

The last edit was 5 minutes ago, and the question itself more then an hour ago.