# Edited in 2 seconds?

Tags: bug, revisions-list, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question asked in future?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36591/question-asked-in-future)

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203659/regex-to-detect-leading-zeros-and-check-the-lenght-from-0-to-12-digits/2203672#2203672) while it was deleted, and it said, `edited in 2 seconds`.

How did *that* happen?

Obligatory freehand circle:

[edited in 2 seconds http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/5113/editedin2seconds.png](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/5113/editedin2seconds.png)

Comment: probably related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36591/question-asked-in-future

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36591/question-asked-in-future

Comment: @ChrisF: beat ya with 5 secs ;-)

Comment: It's not a duplicate - that issue was fixed; this wasn't.

Comment: The root issue is the SO web and DB server clocks have drifted out of sync.

Comment: The blur, drop shadow, multicolor spline and typography are horribly cute. You shall be burned in the stake, so you learn. Next time bring blood, fire and the Hellish Army of Unicorns from Mordor if you want to blend in with Meta.

Comment: @SLaks - I just got this as well (about the same time you asked this question in fact =P) - a comment I posted was listed at 0 secs ago; one after mine was "in 2 secs"

Comment: related to http://serverfault.com/questions/109839/windows-services-not-starting-automatically