# Just curious as to what causes negative time on the front page?

Tags: bug, timestamps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Was a question asked in the future?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36591/was-a-question-asked-in-the-future)

It looks like I am able to reach almost a minute (in some cases) into the future and see posts that haven't been made yet. This probably isn't the biggest priority right now, but I would be interested to hear what causes this bug.

[image]

Comment: A similar thing is happening with chat notifications: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67106/chat-widget-in-ad-space-is-predicting-the-future

Comment: I've also seen it: http://i.imgur.com/NHgHN.png

Comment: @Ether that one has been marked `[status-complete]`, so this would be a new bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clocks were off after our outage - they should now be synced.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the recent events.

[This thing already happend before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36591/was-a-question-asked-in-the-future).