# Why am I getting a downvote for giving a downvote?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
>   [Where is the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq)

I noticed that I had like 202 rep points (is it how they are called?), and I down-vote an answer and I reached the 201, then did it again and then ended up with 200...
Why? I looked for an answer in the FAQ and about question but I cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Downvotes cost the caster 1 Rep point, and the receiver 2 Rep points. Ostensibly, since the person casting the vote has to pay a little bit of their Rep, it helps keep downvoting from being abused.

For more info on Reputation and voting, check out [the FAQ here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) and [the "vote down" privilege wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down).

Answer (score 2):

Downvoting costs 1 reputation point.
It is mentioned in the ["What is reputation?" section](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) of the FAQ

> post is voted down          -2      **(-1 to voter)**