# Could the "edit clash warning" be moved closer to the Save Edits button?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, concurrency

I *love* the new edit system. Even if I don't have enough reputation to perform immediate edits, I can now edit questions and answers to improve their grammar, spelling and structure, and one of the moderators can approve my edits.

Recently I've had a number of "edit clashes", i.e., while I'm editing a question, someone else edited the same question, made mostly the same modifications, and had their edit approved (or has 2000+ reputation).

In order not to give the moderators extra work sorting through proposed edits (and not to make myself look silly for proposing "very minor" changes), it would be nice to get a warning **close to the Submit button** that someone else has edited a question/answer at the same time and to be able to **drop my edit** from the queue.

<strike>Are there any plans to implement such a thing?</strike>
**Edit:** Since this feature is (sort of) implemented<sup>**1**</sup>, I would like to change this into a request to have the notification displayed closer to the Submit button, and to have the option the scrap an edit.

<sup>**1**)</sup> I overlooked the feature since I simply missed the notification bar at the top of the screen:

[image: The "edit clash warning"]

Comment: I have been getting such notification, I think it is already implemented.

Comment: @mzabsky: Perhaps I'm not looking in the right place. Could you take a screenshot and post it here next time you encounter it? I do think **an extra screen to confirm such an edit would be appropriate** and my desire to be able to "cancel" an edit remains...

Comment: Edit the post (the question) now, I have opened the edit screen. I will screenshot it for you :)

Comment: Made some minor modifications now. @mzabsky

Comment: @Arjan: Perhaps I need to rephrase that in a way that explains how my (impaired) eyes failed to pick up said notification. Is it possible to drop an edit?

Comment: [Yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35864/full-contact-moderating)

Comment: [My visual impairment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retinitis_pigmentosa) won't help me in a sword fight... ;-) @Pollyanna

Comment: @OktosiTe I've heard that a [little person, perched on one's shoulders](http://i288.photobucket.com/albums/ll164/stienman/masterblaster.jpg), can help overcome visual limitations, and even give one an edge in such a situation.

Comment: Since March 2011, a warning is shown [after you save as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts/28119#28119).

Comment: @Arjan: If you could post that as an answer, I would accept it. Thanks!

Comment: (Edited mzabsky's answer for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go - it is there:

[image: Screenshot of edit warning]

And a full-blown check while saving the post [is in place since March 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts/28119#28119):

[image: Screenshot of warning messages]

Comment: As far as I know, [it only checks every 30 or 45 seconds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65404/is-concurrent-editing-detection-working-answer-yes-but-only-if-everyone-is-s/65411#65411).

Comment: @Arjan Yeah, I'm aware of that. That's why I agree a manual confirmation of such edit would be nice.

Comment: That is **very** far away from the Submit button; no wonder I missed it. I ignore most notifications at the top, because "I'll get around it later"... @Arjan

Answer (score 0):

This request is similar to [Provide indicator that another user is editing a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73924/provide-indicator-that-another-user-is-editing-a-post), but that request has existed from before the new anyone-can-edit feature. The situation described in that question still exists, because users with enough rep can still edit freely without going through the edit approval process.

Comment: This isn't so much about the approval process as it is (or has become) about **how** users are warned about edit clashes.

Comment: Now that you mention it, the suggested edit stuff might raise a new issue: what if two low rep editors are editing concurrently? Normally a post would be locked once *one* low rep editor has queued a proposed edit. So, if two low rep users are editing (or one quick low rep user and one *slower* >2k user), is the 2nd save operation then rejected? Or also queued? (A rejection would annoy me, if I was trying to help...)